# Is this a load bearing post?

Tags: load-bearing

[image]

I’m wanting to remove this post but not sure if it’s load bearing. Can someone please help?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the floor from beneath where the post is (like from a basement looking up)?

Comment: From the drawing I think the answer is YES.  Why would someone add a random post for no purpose?  Check above and below for additional clues but you may want to consult a structural engineer to be sure before you make any changes.

Comment: Instead of the HVAC plan, could you get a picture of the framing plan the same way you did the HVAC? Even without that, my bet is it is definitely a bearing post.

Comment: There is no basement. I’ve added another picture for reference but the blueprint is all I have. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: then, what's above the post?